# Ensure that property observer didSet manipulates User Interface after viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, rx-swift

I am working on an [open source tutorial](https://github.com/subash-poudel/RxCocoaTableViewDemo) using MVVM, Coordinators and RxSwift. I am constructing all the viewcontrollers and models in the coordinator. Controller has a strong reference to viewmodel and when a viewmodel is set, I would like to perform some UI related actions(using property observer didSet). The problem I am facing is that **didSet** is called before **viewDidLoad** causing a crash.

Stripped down version of ViewController:

```
class MessageVC: UIViewController {
  var viewModel: MessageViewModel! {
    didSet {
      manipulateUI() // crashes
    }
  }

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  manipulateUI() // works fine if setup is correct in coordinator
}
```

Coordinator stripped down version:

```
extension AppCoordinator {

convenience init() {
 let rootVC = MessageVC() // actual construction from storyboard
 let messages = Message.getMessages()
 rootVC.viewModel = MessageViewModel(withMessage: messages)
}
```

My concern is that even though calling **manipulateUI** in viewDidLoad is working for me currently, the app will crash if I forget to set the viewModel from my co-ordinator making me think that I am using a fragile architecture. I really like updating userinterface from didSet but it is called before viewDidLoad.

I know it is a simple problem but from architecture standpoint it seems fragile. Any suggestions, improvements and comments are appreciated a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wont say that cases like this can define wether you are dealing with fragile architecture or not because view controllers has their own life cycle which differs a lot from other objects life cycle. Anyway you can easily avoid crashes here using different approaches. For example :

**Approach 1:**

Put a guard statement at the very beginning of your `manipulateUI` function so this function wont manipulate UI until both view is loaded and model is set. Then call this function on `viewDidLoad` method and when viewModel is set:

```
func manipulateUI(){

    guard let viewModel = self.viewModel , isViewLoaded else {
        return
    }

    //continue manipulation here
}
```

**Approach 2:**

Since you are not sure wether view is loaded when you set the model and don't know if views are initialized yet, you can access the views as optional properties in `manipulateUI` function:

```
func manipulateUI(){

    self.someLabel?.text = self.viewModel.someText    

    //continue manipulation here
}
```

**Approach 3:**

Since you are using RxSwift you can always register an observer for view controller's `isViewLoaded` property and set the data source after you are sure that view is loaded

Comment: I like the third approach. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Crash happens because at this point

```
rootVC.viewModel = MessageViewModel(withMessage: messages)
```

view controller is not initialized.

It won't work the way you're trying to accomplish, you **have to** call *manipulateUI()* inside *viewDidLoad*.